# How to extract username in email address?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

How do I extract the username out of an email address in VBA?

For example - if my email ID is "prateek@gmail.com", then the username is "prateek".

```
Set Reg1 = New RegExp

' \s* = invisible spaces
' \d* = match digits
' \w* = match alphanumeric

With Reg1
    .Pattern = "\w+@gmail\.com"
    .Global = True
End With
If Reg1.Test(emailAddress) Then

    Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(emailAddress)
    For Each M In M1
        ' M.SubMatches(1) is the (\w*) in the pattern
        ' use M.SubMatches(2) for the second one if you have two (\w*)
        Debug.Print M.SubMatches(1)            
    Next
End If
```

It doesn't look like this got any submatch.

Comment: Regex is not necessary here, you can use Left, with InStr looking for @

Comment: @ShaiRado : Damn, I was typing!^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, insread of `RegEx` you could use `Left` combined with `Instr`.

```
Dim usern   As String

'emailAddress = "prateek@gmail.com" ' <-- for debug

usern = Left(emailAddress, InStr(emailAddress, "@") - 1)
MsgBox "UserName is " & usern
```

Comment: Better than `Regexp`. But would suggest the string function Left$ over its variant cousin Left